# Как запускать popup fancybox по прямой ссылке?

Tags: javascript, fancybox

У меня есть popup окно с id="hidden-content" . Мне нужно чтобы это окно открывалось при переходе по ссылке [http://мойсайт/#hidden-content](http://%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82/#hidden-content) . Подскажите пожалуйста, как это реализовать? Перерыл всю инфу о плагине - решения не нашел.

Comment: какая версия fancybox? Не знаю как предыдущие, но в fancybox 3 оно по умолчанию должно открывать по такой ссылке, а чтобы увидеть почему у вас не работает - код ваш видеть нужно

Comment: https://codepen.io/studiocosta/pen/zjqsi/

Comment: 3 версия, у меня сделано так, но по ссылке не открывается попап

Comment: да, всё же в 3 версии открывается окно по ссылке. Но вот по нажатию на крестик оно не закрывается. Почему так ? (